# Can I use Windows 7 Homegroups with Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, homegroup

I'm not currently using the "Homegroup" functionality of Windows 7 because we already have all of our photos, videos, and music on a Windows Server 2008 box.

But Win7 is **really** pushing Homegroup in the UI, so I'm wondering: **is there any way to make files on Windows 2008 Server part of a Homegroup?**

Comment: I would imagine Microsoft would rather you use Windows Home Server as opposed to a full-blown 2008 Server in the home. Most likely they will not expose 2008 Server to Homegroup.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried, but haven't found a way of getting a Windows 2008 stand-alone server to join a homegroup.  That said, I must try W2K8 R2.

However, the old way of creating files shares works well enough even in what is really a workgroup.